# What accessories included by default if I buy/order an SFP module

Tags: sfp

I am buying an SFP module. .I am expecting a duplex LC connector/SFP cable to be included as a default standard accessory.I have not separately mentioned to provide LC connector/SFP cable while ordering as I understood it to be a standard essential free default accessory because on googling such result comes very first when I type SFP modules come with LC connector. Should I expect that the duplex LC connector to be provided with say for example with a D-Link make DEM 310GT 1000BASE LX MiniGigabit Interface Converter SM .The order asks the supplier to provide "1 SFP module" such as D-Link make DEM "310GT 1000BASE LX 1 port Mini Gigabit Interface Converter SM" or equivalent.I have also included a clause stipulating that all material(s)/item(s) should come with standard accessories. So I expect and understand that the supplier is obliged to provide 1 duplex LC connector as this is a standard accessory.I want to know if I am wrong.My question do reputed companies such as Cisco,Huawei,D-Link,TP-Link when the sell SFP module do the ship it with a LC connector/SFP cable as a standard accessory by default or I have order it separatelyI tried to contact D-Link personnel by various means but failed so from the D-Link data Sheet I undertand that SFP module includes duplex LC connector as it a feature of the SFP module of D-Link make DEM 310GT model.The datasheet link is "http://www.dlink.co.in/pdfs/products/DEM-310GT/DEM-310GT_ds.pdf".Hence seeking guidance and advice and information from the learned members here if I am wrong to expect an LC connector/duplex LC connector or SFP cable included without any extra cost with the SFP module as a free standard accessory. I don't know why this type of questions are being marked as irrelevant because in practical a lot of this type of isues frequently arise.Hence I am seeking information/facts/guidance from the learned members.~~~~

---

My comment will be long so I am posting it as an answer please pardon me for this transgression I want to mention that in the The datasheet link is "http://www.dlink.co.in/pdfs/products/DEM-310GT/DEM-310GT_ds.pd the from the header line elaborate product description and the technical features listed under the model DEM 310GT duplex LC connector is mentioned with other things like metallic enclosure to prevent EMI,Also as seen in this link for illustrative purpose only as it is a different but similar enough for comparison of this aspect of the model as can be viewed from the images even if no patch cord is supplied something like this should bne supplied and in a generic way I saw in the  But I would like to point you to this link "https://ourtechplanet.com/sfp-transceivers-explained/" specially this part of the page "The SFP is also known as miniGBIC. GBIC is the Gigabit Interface Converter (another transceiver model) and since the SFP is smaller than GBIC in size, it is called miniGBIC therefore. SFP came into existence later than GBIC and serves the same purpose as GBIC module but because of its smaller size, SFP has replaced the GBIC in most applications today. SFP usually comes with the LC connector (Lucent connector) unlike GBIC that generally comes with the SC (Standard connector).  connectors are fiber-optic cable connectors that are differentiated based on their sizes." and together with the picture that you messaged just few minutes ago I think what I told or at least there is scope of confusion/misunderstanding like I understand that an SFP module should be accompanied with a duplex LC connector by default it seemed to me a duplex LC connector adapter with or without patch cable should be supplied should be supplied as an accessory.also because googling duplex LC connector creates this impression to me.I have made this question rather situation or circumstances have compelled me to seek your advice guidance specially refreeing to the datasheet

Comment: If you order a transciever you get one transciever, nothing more.

Comment: There are simply too many variables to include a cable. For example, what connector should be on the other end, and how long should it be? You buy the cables to fit your requirements.

Comment: Note that the LC Connector mentioned in SFP descriptions is not a separate item, it’s part of the SFP. A connector is not a cable. Cables have connectors, but other things like SFP modules also have connectors.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

SFP modules are overwhelmingly sold without a patch cable. In fact, I've never seen an SFP transceiver being offered in a set with a patch cable.

In addition to the existence of various connector types - LC, SC, ST being the most common - there are multiple end faces - SPC or APC - and some transceivers may even be used with single-mode and multi-mode cabling interchangeably. Also, the required length from SFP to the optical panel differs. It would be highly impractical to generally offer transceiver and patch cable in a set.

The female *LC connector* (jack) is part of the SFP transceiver. It is required as the counterpart for the patch cable's connector.

Comment: I thought that atleast something like this should be supplied https://www.aliexpress.com/item/20-40-80-120KM-1-Gigabit-SM-LC-Connector-SFP-Module-DUAL-Single-Mode-Duplex-Compatible/32901830551.html  the small black connector adaptor i think should atleast accompany as per the data sheet if I order DEM GET310

Comment: That depends per vendor.

Comment: @stacklooker The small black rubber part is a dust cover for the dirt-sensitive optics and isn't always included.